# django ImageField not uploading the file

Tags: python, django, model, upload, imagefield

So i've been googling this issue for the past hour and can't come up with a solution. Basically this is it: in my model.py i have a class that has this

```
class Case(models.Model):
zoomOutImage = models.ImageField('Label', upload_to="zoomOutImage")
```

and in my settings.py i have my media URL/ROOT set up like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(''),'app/static/ds/')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/ds/'
```

which from the webserver should serve out like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ds/zoomOutImage/actinic_granuloma_3.jpg
```

I've installed PIL (inside virtualENV) and there are no errors in uploading, the only issue is when i try uploading the file via the admin panel nothing happens. No errors nothing. The file just simply doesn't get uploaded to the zoomOutImage folder by the development server. Can anyone point me towards why?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Does the target directory *already* exist? Does the server have *write permission* to the directory?

Comment: hi guys, yes it was a permission issue.. i changed to 777 and it worked.. however, now i can't get django to serve the file via HTTP. The url thats supposed to represent the file just throws a 404

Comment: also, do i have to set anything up in urls.py to make these work??

Comment: see my last remark in my answer about static files during development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your file is in a subdir of your root, subdir named 'zoomOutImage'. Or even a file called like that in the root. I remember putting a function call in the upload to string. That function creates a path and filename, using os.join and the filename from the instance. Doing this by head, no example code available right now. But must be able to google this.

Look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime

And by the way, I totally disagree with your answer, you should NEVER use absolute paths in your settings! See this answer [use css in django 1.4 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918043/use-css-in-django-1-4-development/13918899#13918899) for how to use the correct settings and refer to your Project PATH

**EDIT** (after reading your own answer)

Guess you are missing this first step:

this is the path to your settings.py file:

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

and than this is the path to your project dir: (I Am using buildout, so call it buildout, but it's the root of your project):

```
BUILDOUT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, '..'))
```

and from there on you can define everything you want:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BUILDOUT_DIR, 'var', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static_media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BUILDOUT_DIR, 'var', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in your template file refer to the image like:

```
<a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ case.zoomOutImage }}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ case.zoomOutImage }}" width="100%"></a>
```

when your object given to the template is called case

about your question of the urls.
you should add this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'', include('staticfiles.urls')),
    )
```

and see the link above to the question about using css, it's the same problem, but there for finding the css files during development. It's all about the static file places.

Comment: so i ended up getting the file uploads to work, however, now i can't access the files via the specified url in media root.. do you have any idea why this wouldn't be working? The settings are the same as described above

Comment: could be several things, what url are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
# get abspath
def rel(*x):
   return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)
MEDIA_ROOT = rel('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '' #if only your static files are in project folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( rel('static'),) #if only your static files are in project folder
```

use this settings, and everything will work

Comment: Why? What's so special about it? You need to explain your code as well.

Comment: That's a bit weird statement. Like an englishman declaring it's wrench works on all his bolts, so it should work anywhere (what about the metric system?). Like I explained in my answer. The settings declare where to find things, so whether it works depends on your path structure. Looking at your code it will absolutely not work for any of my projects.

Answer (score -2):

so i finally solved my problem. For anyone having this issue in the future do the following:

if you're trying to serve static media files locally on the development server use absolute paths for MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL.

Comment: I Totally disagree, you should never use absolute paths!!! see my answer on how to do this. (I never downvoted an answer... but seriously considered doing so now)

Comment: Sorry, downvoted. Absolute path can be walkaround in extreme situations. But we should never promote "unscalbale" solutions